# Is there a way to find all operations supported by a RestAPI and parameters needed for operations?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

Suppose I created a Rest Service http://SomeServer/api/todo ,and installed on server. Now is there a way for the client to find out what all operations/functionality is provided by this Rest API, just by URL ?

For e.g. if you hit the URL below with get method, it will return the detail of todo item 1
http://SomeServer/api/todo/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what Swagger provides you with. It also has a UI which you can easily hook up to your REST application.

Have a look at:

https://swagger.io/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [hateoas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). It is in plain words like html. When you browse a html page, you have links to navigate to other pages. Similar way, with hateoas your API response has links to hit other related APIs.

Example:

Suppose you have a get user API - `http://serverAddr/user/1`
Suppose the response is user details. With hateoas you will get a list with key as _links which will contain other related urls say `http://serverAddr/delete/user/1`